# how can i use a variable in a function in a global variable?

Tags: python

i have been trying to get some stats in a text based game i have been making. i tried to return the variable from the function but every time i try to put it in a global variable i get a name error. I have looked up many topics about this but what i found didn't help me  much. Here is the code i made to try and fix the game.

```
def HEALTH():
    health =['''
    ===============''','''
    ==============''','''
    =============''','''
    ============''','''
    ===========''','''
    ==========''','''
    =========''','''
    ========''','''
    =======''','''
    ======''','''
    =====''','''
    ====''','''
    ===''','''
    ==''','''
    =''','''
    x''']
    return health
health =HEALTH(health)
print(health[0])
```

Comment: What?... the variable you reference named `health` in the call to `HEALTH` is undefined.  However, since you defined `HEALTH` with no arguments, you don't need it. Instead, you can instantiate it like this: `health = HEALTH()`.

Comment: You don't have a global variable named `health`, and `HEALTH` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Why are you passing an argument to a function that doesn't expect any arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function definition `HEALTH` takes no arguments. Thus, the following line is bound to fail:

```
health =HEALTH(health)
```

In fact, this line looks more like you are trying to create a class named `HEALTH` but it's especially bound to fail because you are using the *variable you are defining* as an argument to the function `health`.

Probably what you are trying to do is accept an argument in the function definition:

```
def HEALTH(health_level):
    health=['''...''']]
    return health[health_level]

print(HEALTH(0))
```

---

We should have some better names for stuff too. Why not call your function something like the following:

```
def get_health(health_level):
    health=['''...''']
    return health[health_level]
```

That way you're not simply using the word "health" over and over again in possibly confusing ways.

Comment: thanks everyone. i got it to work not using an argument when assigning HEALTH() to health. but now i ask could i make health equal a string in the list and if so if i added 1 to health would it turn to health[1] health[2] onward.

Comment: You should accept an answer and ask a new question that's germane to what you want instead of editing your current question or asking more questions in the comments. It just leads to confusing and endless commentary.

Comment: ok thank you and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you've misunderstood a python coding convention.  Typically ALL_CAPS names are reserved for CONSTANTS - variables you don't expect uses to change.  For example you might have a starter value for health like this:

```
HEALTH_DEFAULT = 100

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Health = HEALTH_DEFAULT

class BuffCharacter(Character):
     def __init__(self):
        self.Health = HEALTH_DEFAULT * 2
```

in your case, it looks like you're trying to keep an index of graphic printouts of health for a range of values.  You probably want more like this:

```
HEALTH_DISPLAY = ["=" * i for i in range (10, 0, -1)] + ["X"] # easier on the eyes!

def get_health(val):
    return HEALTH_DISPLAY[val]
```

Comment: i thought range() could only take 2 arguments. what does the + 'x' do?

Comment: 'count down from 10 to 0 by -1' is the range syntax.  The other bit adds "X" to the end of the array like you had in your example